# Special characters are causing an issue while loading a CSV file into db2 table

Tags: csv, db2, utf

My file has data as below

```
abc|def|I completed by degreeSymbol®|210708
```

My load/import statement is below which is run in linux shell script. The Lang environment variable value is= en_US.UTF-8

```
load client from filename of del MODIFIED BY CHARDEL timestampformat="YYYYMMDD" coldel| usedefaults fastparse messages logfilename insert into tablename nonrecoverable;
```

In table the data is getting loaded as

```
abc def (null) 210708
```

And also when I run a select query the get the below error in the db2

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: Caught java.io.CharConversionException
```

Comment: Compare the output of `values HEX('®')` with the HEX() data in the column that has this character.   The UTF-8 encoding for ® (registered sign) should be hex C2AE.   If not, please edit your question to specify the Db2-SERVER platform and the database(or table) encoding.

Comment: IF I insert ® directly into my db2 table and check the hex value. Its C2AE. But when I load the symbol from a CSV file its hex value is AE.

Comment: please specify your Db2-server platform (z/os, i series,  linux/unix/windows/cloud)  and the Db2-server version,  and your jdbc driver version and which tool you are using to run the select in jdbc.

Comment: Since you run this form a linux client with lang en_US.UTF-8 and your table columns seems to record utf-8 chars. Then the | seperated file must be stored with a codepage which is not utf-8 and you have to tell it using `modified by codepage=` [one of these](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=support-supported-territory-codes-code-pages). If the file is encoded with iso-8859-1 then `modified by codepage=819`

Comment: Your load command looks suspicious. You can't use `timestampformat="YYMMDD"`, the only allowed element for years is `YYYY`. There is no `CHARDEL` modifier without its specification, `NOCHARDEL` is valid for your case. You shouldn't have any problems with this "special" character, if your file is really UTF-8 encoded correctly. You may specify the file encoding explicitly with the `codepage=1208`  modifier (or whatever file codepage you have).